# Convenient way to share BLoC between multiple screen

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, provider

I am looking for the most convenient way to share bloc in different screens/pages without providing at top of the material app. For example I have a `Customer` bloc, which is required in `CustomerListScreen` and `CustomerDetailsScreen`. The bloc is created in `CustomerListScreen` and passed it to the `CustomerDetailsScreen` while navigating.

```
Navigator.context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CustomerDetailsScreen(context.read<CustomerBloc>())));
```

This is the procedure I am following right now. Looking for any better approach available out there..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the Bloc a required field of the page,
something like this:

```dart
class CustomerDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget { 
  CustomerDetailsScreen(this.mybloc);

  final Bloc mybloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  BlocProvider.value(
      value: mybloc,
      child: Text('Body...'),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, even if you use a package like AutoRoute you will still be able to provide the bloc to the page route.

Even though I don't like this solution because what if you navigated through a url then you can't pass the bloc to it, for this i recommend to use nested navigation
[read this](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#nested-navigation)

it will look something like this if you use AutoRoute

```dart
@MaterialAutoRouter(              
  replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',              
  routes: <AutoRoute>[              
    AutoRoute(                            
      page: BlocProviderPage,              
      children: [              
        AutoRoute(page: CustomerListScreen),              
        AutoRoute(page: CustomerDetailsScreen),          
      ],              
    ),             
  ],              
)              
class $AppRouter {}
```

```dart
class BlocProviderPage extends StatelessWidget {          
  @override          
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {          
    return BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => MyBloc(),       
            child: AutoRouter(),          
    );          
  }          
}
```

This way both pages will have access to the bloc and you cant navigate to them without a `BlocProviderPage` being a parent of them

Comment: This was perfect for my use case! I'm using auto_route with bloc, and although I've worked with nested routes before (in a screen that contains a BottomNavBar), this solution didn't come to mind when I wanted to share a cubit in a case similar to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use [BlocProvider.value](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocProvider/BlocProvider.value.html).

> BlocProvider can be used to provide an existing bloc to a new portion of the widget tree. This will be most commonly used when an existing bloc needs to be made available to a new route. In this case, BlocProvider will not automatically close the bloc since it did not create it.

```
BlocProvider.value(
  value: context.read<CustomerBloc>(),
  child: CustomerDetailsScreen(),
);
```

Comment: thanks for your ans brother, but its not possible in case of using any navigation related packages like AutoRoute or something like that.

Comment: That's another question, but use AutoRouteWrapper (https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#wrapping-routes) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the context name to other name and pass that context like below

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => AuthBloc(),
      ),
    ],
    child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Log In"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: ContactColors.primaryColor,
        ),
        backgroundColor: ContactColors.offwhite,
        body: BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(listener: (c, state) {
          if (state is AuthError) {
            print("error state");
          } else if (state is AuthSuccess) {
            print("success");
          }
        }, builder: (c, state) {
          if (state is AuthLoading) {
            print("loader");
            return loginbox(c);
          } else {
            return loginbox(c);
          }
          // return widget here based on BlocA's state
        })));
}
```

Comment: Passing context to other view is not a good practice